# Can QVariant be used with QMatrix4x4 and QVector3D etc

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

**tldr** : 
I've noticed that `QMatrix4x4` and  `QVector3D` (and `QVector2D`) all have the function :

```
QVariant QMatrix4x4::operator QVariant() const
```

**Is there a way to get the value of a `QVariant` as a `QMatrix4x4` or `QVector2D` ?**

**context :**

*I'm making a "game engine" (this is more an attempt to learn how to do so) with Qt and OpenGL. And I'm in the process of automatically parsing Shaders to find uniforms and create a QObject class to have a signal and a slot to update the uniform that way. Since it is not possible to mix template and Q_OBJECT I thought that my uniform binder class needed to use QVariants*

Thank you in advance for your precious help.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `v` a QVariant created from a QMatrix4x4, then `QMatrix4x4 matrix = v.value<QMatrix4x4>();` is what you need; the same thing is valid for QVector3D, using `v.value<QVector3D>();`.

For more information: [QVariant#value](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvariant.html#value)